# How convert Html into Prolog

Tags: html, prolog

How convert Html into Prolog?
I need to extract from an html page its tag and i describe it into Prolog.

> **Example**, if my file contains this html code

```
<title>Prove<title>
<select id="data_nastere_zi" name="data_nastere_zi">
```

i should get

```
title(Prove),
select(id(data_nastere_zi)).
```

I tried to see various library but i couldn't.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse *well formed* HTML using SWI-Prolog [library(sgml)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%280,%270%27,swi%28%27/doc/packages/sgml.html%27%29%29), in particular [load_html/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=load_html/3).

My experience,  scraping 'real world' websites, isn't really pleasant, because of insufficient error handling.

Anyway, when you will have loaded the page structure, you will have available [library(xpath)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=xpath/3) to inspect such complex data.

*edit* getting a table inside a div:

```
xpath(Page, //div, Div),
xpath(Div, //table, Table)...
```

Comment: Is it possible identify the neighboring sections in a HTML page with this library? For example with `div` or if a `table` is neighboring to another `table`.

Comment: library(xpath) allows that, but in a rather peculiar way: usually an XML parsed element make available a *parent* pointer, that's missing here. When you get an element, you can refine your pattern, going 'deeper', but not there is now way to go 'upward'. Then you need to work top down: select the outer element *and* then peek inside.

Comment: And if i want to describe the neighboring sections, for example a page that is composed of three sections. How do I say that a section is neghboring to another section and not included in another section?

Comment: instead of the search operator (double bar) use the single bar (parent/child), or - equivalently - inspect the elements list. There are also the possibility to use indexes, but things become a bit hairy...

Answer (score 0):

SWI-Prolog has a package for SGML/XML parsing based on the SWI-Prolog interface to SP by Anjo Anjewierden: ["SWI-Prolog SGML/XML parser"](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%280,%270%27,swi%28%27/doc/packages/sgml.html%27%29%29).